# How to combine two array and chunk it if the key is same

Tags: php, arrays

I'am bulding an app with laravel, and I have a problem, I have two array in php :

```
Array1
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 16
    [4] => 17
    [5] => 17
    [6] => 17
    [7] => 17
)

Array2
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
)
```

in this case i can not to use array_chunk because the value of array2 is dinamic and key of array1 must not be same if i combine it, so, how i can combine it to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple `foreach` loop:

```
$arr1 = [15,15,16,16,17,17,17,17];
$arr2 = [0,1,1,2,0,1,2,3];

$result = [];
foreach($arr1 as $k => $v){
    $result[$v][] = $arr2[$k]; 
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )
)
```

Comment: I agreed. @AlivetoDie

Comment: @Virb  sorry can't do that. i got it. both array indexes need to be identical

Answer (score 2):

```
$array1 = 
[
    0 => 15,
    1 => 15,
    2 => 16,
    3 => 16,
    4 => 17,
    5 => 17,
    6 => 17,
    7 => 17,
];

$array2 = 
[
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 2,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 1,
    6 => 2,
    7 => 3,
];


$arr = array_unique($array1);
print_r($arr);
$newarray = [];
foreach($arr as $ar){
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
       if($ar == $value){
         $newarray[$value][] =$array2[$key];   
       } 
    }
}

print_r($newarray);
```